# Find Expire Time for an access token

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is there any way to use the graph api to find out when a page access token, or application token will expire?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is now an API version of the debugger tool.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/access-token-debug/

Answer (score 31):

**Update:** There is a new API endpoint to access information about an access token. You can find info here: **[Debugging Access Tokens and Handling Errors](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/debugging-and-error-handling)**

`https://graph.facebook.com/debug_token?input_token=INPUT_TOKEN&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN`

- input_token: the Access Token to debug
- access_token: your App Access Token or a valid User Access Token from a developer of the app.

--

You should try to make sure that you store each token's expiration time along with the access token when you get it. For a page access token, that means storing the expiration time of the user access token. If you would like to manually discover expiration times for tokens you have today, you should use Facebook's [Access Token Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/access_token) tool. However, you should not be relying on expiration times alone -- in practice, many tokens will expire much earlier than their expiration time.

**Application access tokens will never expire**, unless the application secret key is reset.

**Page access tokens last up to 60 days** (5184000 seconds), but more importantly, they last as long as the user access token that was used to acquire them. So [they will be invalidated](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/access-token-expiration/) as soon as the user that you got them from:

- logs out of FB.
- changes password.
- deauthorizes your application.

Basically, when you lose the user's token, you will lose the page's token. Instead, you should retrieve page access tokens once per user access token. If you throw out a user access token, throw out the page token. **You should not be trying to store page access tokens for any significant period of time.** Instead you should get them as needed and forget them when a user's session dies.

To get a new page access token:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/PAGEID?fields=access_token&access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Comment: I dont think this is true, offline access is no more, so all tokens last maximum of 60 days (if server side auth flow occurred).  The tokens do not expire when the user logs out.  I need a way to be able to use my token to find out if it expires, not sure how your answer helps me ?

Comment: The tokens *do* verifiably expire when the user logs out. Would you like steps to verify that this is the case?

Comment: Not all user tokens last 60 days (e.g., JS SDK tokens last 2 hours). As I described above, page access tokens are tied to users and are invalidated at the same time that user access tokens are invalidated.

Comment: Do you have any documentation to back this up?  Because I just logged out, took the page access token and entered it into Facebooks debugger and it's still valid.

Comment: I'm talking about logging out on behalf of your app using the API logout endpoint. For example, FB.logout() or $facebook->getLogoutUrl. Here is some documentation that explains what I am talking about: [Handling Invalid and Expired Access Tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/access-token-expiration/), [FB.logout](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout/)

Comment: @Nix AndrewF is correct, please also be aware of the [Removal of offline_access permission](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/)

Comment: I had some trouble finding what my app access_token was. Turns out it's just APP_ID|APP_SECRET. If your APP_ID was 123456789 and APP_SECRET was asdfasdfasdfasdf your call would be: graph.facebook.com/debug_token?input_token=INPUT_TOKEN&access_token=123456789|asdfasdfasdfasdf

Comment: New URL for docs about handling expired tokens - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/debugging-and-error-handling#errors

Comment: The link at the top of the answer does already redirect, but I will update it to the proper URL. Kudos

Answer (score 7):

Access Token Debugger

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/access_token

Does not use the Graph API... but a very useful tool for manual debugging.

Comment: I want a programatic way to check... aka, I *want* to use the graph api.

Comment: +1'd not for it being an answer to the OP question but it is a useful tool and exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6):

I would like to repeat this question for the current version of the API since I've come to a situation when Facebook doc clearly does not describe what is happening:

- no expiry dates when requesting a new long-lived token with `fb_exchange_token`
- no expiry dates when requesting debug_token information (`expires_at = 0`)
- it does reply with an expiration date when redirecting the user to the auth page for the first time, but that does not help as I cannot extract the long-lived expiration date nor it will reply with this information for the second time

The debug tool here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken says "Expires: Never".

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it worked with me. Get the token with your app and paste it in the graph explorer as the token to be used for queries. Click on the info a see the expiration date.
[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4Sdd.png)

I hope it works for you too.

Comment: Please add some content from the link

Comment: Sorry but i didn't caught you. What do you mean ?

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension

From the page above:

> Access tokens on the web often have a lifetime of about two hours, but
>   will automatically be refreshed when required. If you want to use
>   access tokens for longer-lived web apps, especially server side, you
>   need to generate a long-lived token. A long-lived token generally
>   lasts about 60 days.