# Facebook SDK Integration with Android app

Tags: android, facebook, expired-sessions

I am integrating Facebook SDK in my android app for Facebook login functionality.
In `onSuccess()`, I am checking token expiry time, but time is coming of 
2016.

```
 LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(final LoginResult loginResult) {
                String date=String.valueOf(loginResult.getAccessToken().getExpires());
                }
        }
```

Can anyone suggest how to get proper expiry time?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149065/find-expire-time-for-an-access-token

Comment: This issue is resolved by removing my current app form facebook account. and try with re-login in my android app. so in my facebook account new entry will create for android app. and it will work fine.